# finding how many times the digit 5 appears within 0 - 4322

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strstr

This code doesnt seem to work for me. it outputs the number 17 which is obviously wrong.the counter should go up if it encounters numbers like 5, 15, 25, 50 ect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int counter; 
    char num[4322];

    for (i = 1; i < sizeof(num); i++){
        num[i] = i;
        if ( strstr(&num[i], "5")){
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    } 

    printf("%d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `int counter;` --> `int counter=0;` 2) `char num[4322];`.. `num[i] = i;` : `char` can hold 0~255 or -128~127 3) `strstr(&num[i], "5")` : `&num[i]` isn't C-String.

Comment: interesting how it actually gives this result, with 17 ~= 4322 / 255. Since each char is in 0-255, you end up having 17 0-terminated strings, each of which contains the char '5' (ascii code 0x35) exactly once.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't convert the numbers to strings, and you passed what are not a null-terminated strings to `strstr()`.
You also forgot to initialize `counter`.

You should check the digits one-by-one. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int max = 4322;
    int target = 5;
    int i, cur, counter = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        for (cur = i; cur > 0; cur /= 10) {
            if (cur % 10 == target) counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really udnerstand this. so imagine i=50.
 for (cur = i; cur > 0; cur /= 10) {
            if (cur % 10 == target) counter++;
        }
50 % 10 = 0 so the counter would not increment

Comment: @Bossrevz Note the `for` loop's third clause is `cur /= 10` and the loop executes while `cur > 0` is true. This means that `cur = 50 / 10` (5), and `5 > 0` is true, so 50 will be counted. It just won't be counted on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are many problems in this code.

```
char num[4322];
```

This is an array of 4322 characters.  You probably didn't want that, I'm not sure why it is here.

```
num[i] = i;
```

This is invalid, because you cannot assign large numbers to a `char`.  This will not convert the number to a string, this will convert the number to a `char` which is different.  So 5 does not become `"5"` but it becomes `\x05`.

```
strstr(&num[i], "5")
```

This will search for `"5"`, but since the array is not nul-terminated, it is incorrect.  Also note that you are storing

```
int counter;
```

Note that `counter` is uninitialized.  This is an error.

Here is a similar program, which is correct (but not "efficient" per se):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int counter = 0; // initialize to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 4322; i++) {
        // Put the number in a string
        char buf[10];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", i);
        // Count 5s
        for (char *p = buf; *p; p++) {
            if (*p == '5') {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", counter);
}
```

Note that @MikeCAT's answer skips the int -> string conversion, which is somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: Shouldn't `55` be counted as two `5`s?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Your new code contains an infinite loop: `p` has to be incremented after being checked if it is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks again, and this is why I don't like doing string processing in C.

Comment: `char buf[10];` is skimpy for a 32-bit int.  Suggest `char buf[12];` for `"-2147483648"`, or just double it for growth `char buf[24];`  (Ah now see OP said `0 - 4322`.

Comment: @chux: It's not skimpy for 4322, thank you very much.  Trying to solve the OP's problem, not predict some future problem he may have.

Comment: Hmm wonder why `4322`? Perhaps easier for a prof to google 4322 and see who used SO for homework?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Like i have a bit of knowledge in java, if anyone can tell and just did it as if it were java syntax, but in C you have to use all these function terms like snprintf which i just google'd right now and pointers and it just feels so foreign to me :/

Comment: @Bossrevz: Java has pointers, you just can't do arithmetic on them or cast them.